# Rails console doesn't start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'll write down my path and version of ruby and rails on my machine first then the error I'm having.

`which rails`

`/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin/rails`

`rails -v`

`Rails 7.0.1`

`which ruby`

`/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/bin/ruby`

`ruby -v`

`ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x86_64-darwin21]`

When I try to run `rails console`, it does not run but show these options:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]              # Skip namespace (affects only isolated engines)
      [--skip-collision-check], [--no-skip-collision-check]  # Skip collision check
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                          # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                             # Default: /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                  # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                  # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                             # Default: sqlite3
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                          # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                      # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]      # Skip Action Mailer files
      [--skip-action-mailbox], [--no-skip-action-mailbox]    # Skip Action Mailbox gem
      [--skip-action-text], [--no-skip-action-text]          # Skip Action Text gem
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]      # Skip Active Record files
      [--skip-active-job], [--no-skip-active-job]            # Skip Active Job
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]    # Skip Active Storage files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]        # Skip Action Cable files
  -A, [--skip-asset-pipeline], [--no-skip-asset-pipeline]    # Indicates when to generate skip asset pipeline
  -a, [--asset-pipeline=ASSET_PIPELINE]                      # Choose your asset pipeline [options: sprockets (default), propshaft]
                                                             # Default: sprockets
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]            # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-hotwire], [--no-skip-hotwire]                  # Skip Hotwire integration
      [--skip-jbuilder], [--no-skip-jbuilder]                # Skip jbuilder gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                        # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]          # Skip system test files
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]                # Skip bootsnap gem
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                    # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                  # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  --master, [--main], [--no-main]                            # Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository main branch
      [--rc=RC]                                              # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                                # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                    # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
      [--minimal], [--no-minimal]                            # Preconfigure a minimal rails app
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                              # Choose JavaScript approach [options: importmap (default), webpack, esbuild, rollup]
                                                             # Default: importmap
  -c, [--css=CSS]                                            # Choose CSS processor [options: tailwind, bootstrap, bulma, postcss, sass... check https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                    # Don't run bundle install

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory,
    or in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/rails/railsrc if XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

Comment: Are you running the console command while inside the directory of the Rails application you are trying to develop?

Comment: I am trying to run some ruby script in the rails console. I have no experience in ruby or rails. I'm just following a tutorial to create a group access token on for gitlab api and the tutorial is using ruby

Comment: then maybe try running the irb command in cli/terminal, it will give you Ruby's interactive session where you can type in and run code.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I am trying to start a Rails console session:
For Omnibus installations

``sudo gitlab-rails console``  gives error: ``sudo: gitlab-rails: command not found`` . Do you have some idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a Rails app? Looks like you're running `rails console` in a directory that has no Rails app created yet.

You should create a new app using `rails new [app_name]`, then run `rails console`. Or, make sure that you're in the root directory of your existing Rails app.

Comment: I figured it out before you commented but thanks.

Comment: glad to help! Hope you enjoy Rails.